# Nginx, WSGI, Django - setting up web server

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, wsgi

I'm quite new to setting up a web server and have been following these guides:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html
https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281

Since I'm working off a mac, I installed nginx through Homebrew: `brew install nginx`. I have been struggling to get my nginx server to serve my Django static file.

I have followed the guides and have copied their `mysite_nginx.conf` and changed it according to my project paths:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /Users/Simon/Documents/WebServer/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /Users/Simon/Documents/WebServer/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/Simon/Documents/WebServer/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Since I'm running the server locally, I don't have a server name and have left it as `.example.com` as per the file above. I have also tried changing it to `127.0.0.1` (as I'm running it on localhost) but that also doesn't work.

After completing this file, I symlinked the file to nginx as per the guide - however the folder `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` did not exist so I had to create it myself first and then issue the following command:

```
sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I followed the guide as is in their "Deploying static files" section and stopped and started my nginx server on mac by:

```
sudo nginx -s stop
sudo nginx
```

Now, they have asked me to go to this address to see whether my media.png was served:

http://example.com:8000/media/media.png

It was not served because I don't think Chrome can distinguish between `example.com` on the internet and `example.com` on my localhost. I get a `This site can’t be reached. example.com took too long to respond error` on Chrome.

so I tried:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media.png

But still I get an `This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect` error.

Here is my file structure for my project:

[image]

Here is what is contained within uwsgi_params:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

I'm not sure if the guide are outdated. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The below is the settings.py file:

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: you can't use example.com as a local domain. You can still use localhost itself, but what if you need to serve 2 sites? In this case you should create local third level domains (editing your hosts file). Though these are all complications which doesn't have much sense to me, just go with the dev server in development and arm nginx and uwsgi in production

Comment: Yes - I know that I can go with the dev server but i still need to prepare for the time when my webserver will go live into production.

Comment: Do you really want to deploy Django on your Mac? Normally we just develop on a Mac. You must execute `./manage.py runserver` and that's it—no need for nginx and uwsgi. Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: I just wanted to test to see whether the combination of django, nginx and wsgi will work together before I deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding all the DNS stuff as I might bore you, they've even pointed out that you need to substitute example.com for your own IP address/'localhost'. 
So, 
change your 'servername' in your mysite_nginx conf file to localhost.
If that doesn't work, try checking the nginx logs in (as you've installed nginx via Homebrew):

> /usr/local/var/log/nginx

By the way, I strongly suggest you check out some short guidebooks to networking as it seems to confuse you somewhat.

Comment: I have tried the localhost route 127.0.0.1 and it still gave me an error. The error.log file says: 2017/08/30 10:11:16 [notice] 74975#0: signal process started but gave no other info.

Comment: added the settings.py file

Comment: Okay, try checking the permissions for your mysite folder next, they should at least be 711.

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: Execute 'ls -la' /your/mysite/root/folder/ or just cd there and execute 'ls -la'

Answer (score 0):

**Changes to be made to configuration file:**
upsteam and server blocks should be defined inside a http block.
Also, an events block should be provided, which can be empty

Comment: maybe you could elaborate further, e.g. by providing code samples?